# running a function and saving multiple outputs in matlab with different inputs

Tags: matlab

lets say you have some function

```
x = foo(alpha, beta);
```

and you want to test the function for different alpha values while saving the different x values with a name associated to the different alpha values.

For example if `alpha = 1:1:10;`
then then i would like to save `x_1 , x_2 ,........,x_9 , x_10` as separate results

I've tried running different loops and such but I can't figure out how to keep the x values from being replaced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this

For example, if you want to save results to disk, you can run

```
alpha = 1:10;

for ii=1:length(alpha)

  x = foo(alpha(ii),beta);

  %# save to disk
  save(sprintf('run_%i.mat',ii),'x');

end
```

If, instead, you want to store all outputs, so that you can plot, for example, you can store them in an array

```
alpha = 1:10;
x = zeros(size(alpha));

for ii=1:length(alpha)

  x(ii) = foo(alpha(ii),beta);

end

%# now you can plot the results
plot(alpha,x)
```

Note that the above assumes that the output of `foo` is scalar. If the output is always a `m-by-n` array, you initialize `x` as `zeros(m,n,length(alpha))`, and assign `x(:,:,ii)` each loop. If the output is arrays of different size, you initialize `x` as a cell array, as `x = cell(size(alpha))`, and assign the output of `foo` to `x{ii}`.